# How to transfer my work to another size class while keeping the connections?

Tags: ios, xcode, size-classes

I just started using `xcode` and I began building my first app for iPhone (portrait view only)  in the `wCompact hRegular` size class. I later realized I should have been using the `wCompact hAny` size class to do this. I tried copying and pasting the work I did on the `wCompact hRegular` size class to the `wCompact hAny` one, but I ran into trouble as the connections to my code were lost in the process. Is there a way to get my work copied into the `wCompact hAny` size class without losing my connections, or do I need to redo all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As I saw in every WWDC video of Apple they start designing from size class `wANY hANY`, you should start designing from `wANY hANY`.

2) There is reason behind that,If you do so it will visible is all your size classes.So the Basic design should always be in size class `wANY hANY`,

3) If you want to do something specific to that `size class` then design in that class.eg.Say you want to show a label only for iPhone 4,5,6 your could add it in `wCompact hRegular`.It will not be visible in IPAD

4) This apple develor site [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnablingAdaptiveSizeDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH1-SW1) has given how to start.

Comment: As an addendum, if you're not using git, you should learn it. It's not hard and it'll bail you out of bad situations. http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

Comment: @Eric:Please mark accepted if the answer helped you.If so it will help community to predict right answer.

Comment: Thank you for your responses!

Comment: @Eric:Glad to help you.